# Unable to bake fluid after changing cache folder

Tags: fluid-simulation, baking, windows, cache

So I've been studying Blender's fluid simulation and I realized that after I set the folder's path to somewhere else other than Window's temp folder (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp) the bake progress bar stays at 0% for some seconds and then disappears. No errors or anything (the log shows no errors either) . I tried this out on my Linux machine back at home and it worked fine (the Windows machine is at work).

Comment: I've never had that problem. You should probably give more information about your system in order to find a solution.

Comment: @Jbergman - you are lucky mann :D I have this problem often.  Also if I use default settings for cache. When I change folder, sometiems work, sometimes does't. The same on Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I had a special character (german ü) in the path of the blend-file, after removing that, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with Fluids for the past month and also have not seen this problem. I can assign a folder and name for the cache and then read it back with a time offset in a different scene, and it all works fine.

Sometimes data corruption can creep into a file and produce odd behavior. Have you tried starting from scratch in a fresh startup?

Could also be something to do with your fluids setup. Perhaps you could post a file?